Send WhatsApp messages immediately to new leads
We want to send immediate WhatsApp messages to new leads who fill out a form on our website. Currently, we are using Sinch on Marketing Cloud to send these messages.
To send a WhatsApp message to a new lead/contact, we must first import them into the WhatsApp channel using a data import definition.
This involves updating a Data Extension with the lead's details and then running the import activity in Automation Studio.
However, since the automation runs at minimum 15-minute intervals, we must incorporate a 15-minute delay for sending.
Is there a way to bypass this, perhaps programmatically?
Maybe adding a script into the WhatsApp template the imports the contact into the channel?

You might want to look into the OTT Transactional Messaging API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_transactional_messaging_ott?meta=Summary
I don't know if it works with the Sinch integration though

@RafałWolsztyniak thanks. I tried it and got this error MCMS_UTM_Runtime_ObjectNotFound: TriggeredSend definition, definitionKey=<my string>. I tried to use the msg name and the Customer Key. Any idea where to get the correct value?
